# Rayleigh quotient ($|r(q)-\lambda|=O(||q-x||_2^2)$ ?)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

how to show $|r(q)-\lambda|=O(\|q-x\|_2^2)$

$r(q)=q^*Aq/(q^*q)$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $A$ is a Hermitian matrix. $x$ is the unit eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. and $q$ is a unit vector. vectors are allowed to have complex entries.

also I know how to show:

$|r(q)-\lambda|\le2.\|A\|_2.\|q-x\|_2$

also ,for $A$ hermitaian, $\|A\|_2$ is the largest singular value(=largest eigenvalue)

Comment: What is $v$ in this case? Do we know if $A$ is symmetric?  What is $x$ in this case?  Are vectors/matrices allowed to have complex entries?

Comment: If you know how to show that $|r(q)-\lambda|\le2.||A||.||q-x||$, doesn't that answer your question?  In other words, if $|r(q) - \lambda| \leq C\|q - x\|$, then we certainly have $|r(q) - \lambda| = O(\|q - x\|^2)$.

Comment: Also, I suspect you mean $|r(q) - \lambda|^2$

Comment: I read that  $|r(q)-\lambda|=O(||q-x||^2)$ is only for symmetric matrices. and the other inequality is for any matrix A

Comment: Oh, I guess you mean $O(\|q-x\|^2)$ as $\|q-x\| \to 0\dots$  I'll think about it